# Remove all but N files from directory recursively

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I would like to whittle down a large database from the command line to N files, very similar to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1186350/delete-all-but-1000-random-files-in-a-directory?newreg=abb9ce418fa04ba78ad90fcb04734b3b) question does. The only difference is that most of my files are in sub-directories, so I was wondering if there was a quick fix to my problem or if it would require more in depth action. Currently, my command looks like (with the `(N+1)` replaced with the appropriate number):

```
find . -type f | sort -R | tail -n +(N+1) | xargs rm
```

I originally thought this would work because find by nature is recursive, and then I tried adding the `-r` (recursive flag) around the `rm` as the output indicates that it is randomly selecting files, but can't find them to delete. Any ideas?

**EDIT:** My new command looks like this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -R | tail -n +(N+1) | xargs -0 rm
```

and now I get the error saying `rm: missing operand`. Also, I am on a CentOS machine so the `-z` flag is unavailable to me.

**EDIT #2** This command runs:

```
find . -type f -print0 | sort -R | tail -n +(N+1) | xargs -0 -r rm
```

but when I execute a `find . -type f | wc -l` to get the number of files in the directory (which should be N if the command worked correctly) has not changed from the starting amount of files.

Comment: Note on #2: neither plain `sort` nor plain `tail` works with null-terminated strings the way you want.

Comment: This is why I wish I could use the -z command as that is what the internet says to do. Unfortunately CentOS doesn't have this flag. Do you know if there is a way around this?

Comment: If you really need `-print0`, you should clearly state it because (in my opinion) this is the only thing that makes your question not a duplicate of the linked one. Then you should also explicitly mention the inability to use `-z` (with `sort`? `tail`? both?).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I am not really sure if I for certain need `-print0`, but many of the related solutions I have seen have used it. In the question I originally linked, I saw solutions with and without it and so I have tried it both ways.

Comment: In what way your original command fails? Any error message(s)?

Comment: The original does not yield any error messages with respect to the command itself, but it does fail because when it tries to delete the files, it says, "No such file or directory" for every single one of the randomly selected files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to use `find … -print0` and you cannot use `-z` with `sort` and/or `tail`, there is a possible, yet cumbersome workaround (substitute `(N+1)` as usual):

```
find . -type f -printf "%i\n" | sort | uniq | sort -R | tail -n +(N+1) |
   while read i; do
      find . -type f -inum "$i" -delete
   done
```

The dirty trick is we use inode numbers instead of paths.

The inner `find` removes all files with the given inode number under the current directory, so if some files are hardlinked one to another then you will either lose them all or keep them all.

Preliminary `sort | uniq` is to avoid a mishap when you lose too much because of duplicate inode numbers because of hardlinks. You may end up with more than `N` filenames, pointing to up to `N` distinct inodes in total.

In case your `find` doesn't understand `-delete`, use [`-exec rm {} +`](https://superuser.com/a/1222237/432690).

Comment: Just tried this (had to modify slightly to run directly from command line and not as a script), and it worked perfectly. Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I did this on osx like

```
find . -type f -print | sort | uniq | sort --random-sort | tail -n +1000 | xargs rm -f
```

Where my N was `1000`. You can then doublecheck it's the right number of files remainig with `ls | wc -l`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/20307392/630752